# How to configure EC2 to put a container in service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

How can I configure EC2 to make sure it brings a docker container which runs a tomcat instance in to service only after the startup is done properly ?
It has to make sure the below line is printed by tomcat 
org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 177052 ms

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you are trying to do or what your end goal is. It seems weird that you are running a single container on an instance.

I would try and use EC2 Container Service first as that will give you the best results. This allows you to run containers in clusters and will manage bringing them up and the healthchecks.

If you must bring it up onto an EC2 instance then the best way to accomplish this would be with a mix of user data (a script that runs at boot) and healthchecks by a load balancer or something to ensure that your tomcat container is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by leveraging ecs health check grace period and set the grace period according to your app startup time 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/12/amazon-ecs-adds-elb-health-check-grace-period/